# Script to parse CSV values

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, parsing, csv

I'm using this code to parse the values and store them in List.  The first row has names which are getting stored fine.  But when storing values,  only the second row is bring saved. I'm not sure what edit I need to make so that it parses all other rows as well.

Please see image and code below.

[image]

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();                   // List to store Key names
List<string> values = new List<string>();                  // List to store key values

using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
    names = stream.ReadLine().Split(',').ToList();         // Seperate key names and store them in a List
    values = stream.ReadLine().Split(',').ToList();        // Seperate key values and store them in a list
}
```

Comment: So far your code does exactly what you describe - please edit your question so it is clear what you expect and what does not work. Type of `values` variable and lack of any iteration clearly indicate that code should just read one line of data from CSV.

Comment: Side note: Please consider to use existing CSV parsers... Your code handles escaped quotes completely wrong...

Comment: What its not doing is that its not storing values from row 3 onwards. It only stores row 2.

Comment: Why you don't use CsvHelper or FileHelpers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if something like this works better:

```
    // List to store Key names
    List<string> names = new List<string>();                                                 
    // List to store key values
    List<List<string>> values = new List<string>();                                               

    using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        if(!stream.EndOfStream)
        {
            // Seperate key names and store them in a List
            names = stream.ReadLine().Split(',').ToList();
        }                     
        while(!stream.EndOfStream)
        {
            // Seperate key values and store them in a list
            values.Add(stream.ReadLine().Split(',').ToList());                 
        }
    }
```

This changes your values list to be a list of a list of strings so that each row will a list of string

While this probably isn't the best way to parse a .csv, if your data is consistent and the file format is strongly consistent you can probably get away with doing it like this.  As soon as you try this with odd values, quoted strings, strings with commas, etc., you'll need a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

i have written the code for grid view make changes it to a list.I think it will help

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            string s = FileUpload1.FileName.Trim();
            if (s.EndsWith(".csv"))
            {
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/data/" + s));
                string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("~/data/" + s));
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
               // Array.Sort(readText);

                for (int i = 0; i < readText.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        string str = readText[0];
                        string[] header = str.Split(',');

                        dt.TableName = "sal";
                        foreach (string k in header)
                        {
                            dt.Columns.Add(k);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

                        string str1 = readText[i];
                        if (readText[i] == ",,,,")
                        {
                            break;
                        }


                        string[] rows = str1.Split(',');
                        if (dt.Columns.Count == rows.Length)
                        {

                            for (int z = 0; z < rows.Length; z++)
                            {
                                if (rows[z] == "")
                                {
                                    rows[z] = null;

                                }

                                dr[z] = rows[z];
                            }
                            dt.Rows.Add(dr);


                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Label1.Text = "please select valid format";
                        }
                    }


                }

                //Iterate through the columns of the datatable to set the data bound field dynamically.
                ds.Merge(dt);
                Session["tasktable"] = dt;
                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    BoundField bf = new BoundField();

                    bf.DataField = col.ToString();
                    bf.HeaderText = col.ColumnName;
                    if (col.ToString() == "Task")
                    {
                        bf.SortExpression = col.ToString();
                    }
                    GridView1.Columns.Add(bf);

                }
                GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                GridView1.DataBind();


            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Text = "please select a only csv format";
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "please select a file";
        }
        }
```